# Creating a list of checkboxes with values from a php array as its label

Tags: php

I want to create a list of checkboxes with values from a php array as its label. I want it to look like

> Here is the list of students whose schedules are saved:
>
> [checkbox] Robb
>
> [checkbox] Catelyn
>
> [checkbox] Lady Stoneheart

but my code does not work.

Here's my code:

```
<?php

    $students = $_SESSION['students'];

    echo "Here is the list of students whose schedules are saved:<br/><br/>";

    echo "<form action='checkbox-form.php' method='post'>
    Load student?<br/>";

    foreach ($students as $stud) {

        echo "<br/><input type='checkbox' name=" . $stud . " value='load' />";
    }

    echo "<br/><br/><input type='submit' name='formSubmit' value='Submit' />
    </form>";

?>
```

The array is not the problem because it contains the proper values when I print it through foreach.

Comment: What do you mean by 'it doesn't work'? It doesn't do anything? Produces the wrong data? You're not outputting anything other than the HTML for the checkbox - there's no label being echoed.

Comment: Oh snap. Closing this question for total self-fail.

Comment: Nothing another coffee wouldn't fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easier to do it this way:

On the form:

```
foreach ($students as $stud) {

    echo "<br/><input type='checkbox' name=\"students[]\" value='$stud' />$stud<br>";
}
```

On the handler to see what it's passing:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Comment: Wait... gotta escape my slashes. There, that should do it.

Comment: Neat. I changed the double quotes in students[] to single ones and it worked. I didn't know about the escape slashes, heh. Any tips on how to align the checkboxes? It looks like a zigzagged list because the CSS of the page I'm displaying it to is aligned center, and some of the names vary in length so it looks weird on a center align. Am I making sense?

Comment: You can wrap them in a `<div>` or a `<p>` and assign a width and make them float. You can also make them an ordered list `<ol>` and apply styling to `<li>` tags with floats.

Answer (score 1):

If all of the "value" fields are "load", which in this case they are, nothing can happen because your PHP won't see anything different value-wise.
You should set the name value of all of these checkboxes to the same thing, and set the value to the student's name (though that's bad design- you should be setting the value to the numeric DB id that represents the student- what if you have students with the same name?)

So:

```
for($i = 0; i < count($students); $i++) {
    $s = $students[$i];
    echo "<br/><input type='checkbox' name="students[]" value='$s' />";
}
```

In this case name="students[]" is the students ARRAY which you can access via $_POST['students'] as an array.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've confused the "name" attribute for the label. A few notes:

- "name" is used as the name of the parameter passed to the backend
- "value" is the value that will be assigned to that parameter if the checkbox is checked

So the line in your foreach should look more like:

```
echo '<br /><input type="checkbox" name="students[]" value="'.$stud.'" />'.$stud;
```

If Robb and Catelyn are checked you will get the below in the $_POST['students'] variable server side:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Robb
  [1] => Catelyn
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($students as $student){
echo "<br/><input type='checkbox' name=" . $student . " value=" . $student . " />";
echo "<label for name=" . $student . ">" . $student . "</label>";   
}
```